# Trying to make base url in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Here is the code please check what's wrong i did

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/e-biotech/';
@define(SITEURL,$config['base_url']);
```

Comment: what is issue your facing?

Comment: `constants.php` will load before `config.php`, so you cant use config file variable inside constant file, you can create constant of base url and use in config file.

Comment: trying to link css file in header like http://localhost/e-biotech/css/style.css

Comment: the code is still in config.php not in constants.php

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `@define(SITEURL,$config['base_url']);`

**Config.php**

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/e-biotech/';
```

Now in your view file

you can sue **site_url()** as below

```
<head>
        <base href="<?= site_url() ?>">
```

And your assets will load perfectly

Comment: i am using like this on header <base href="<?= site_url() ?>">

Comment: going to remove @define(SITEURL,$config['base_url']); then let's see

Comment: okay, tell me if any issue or not getting assets.